# How to pass InMemoryUploadedFile as a file?

Tags: django, openai-whisper

User records audio, audio gets saved into audio Blob and sent to backend. I want to get the audio file and send it to openai whisper API.

```
  files = request.FILES.get('audio')
  audio = whisper.load_audio(files)
```

[image: Error]

I've tried different ways to send the audio file but none of it seemed to work and I don't understand how it should be sent. I would prefer not to save the file. I want user recorded audio sent to whisper API from backend.

Edit*

The answer by AKX seems to work but now there is another error
[image]

Edit 2*

He has edited his answer and everything works perfectly now. Thanks a lot to @AKX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`load_audio()` **requires** a file on disk](https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/7858aa9c08d98f75575035ecd6481f462d66ca27/whisper/audio.py#L22), so you'll need to cater to it – but you can use a temporary file that's automagically deleted outside the `with` block. (On Windows, you may need to use `delete=False` because of sharing permission reasons.)

```
import os
import tempfile

file = request.FILES.get('audio')
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=os.path.splitext(file.name)[1], delete=False) as f:
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        f.write(chunk)
    f.seek(0)

try:
    audio = whisper.load_audio(f.name)
finally:
    os.unlink(f.name)
```

Comment: This seems to work but I am getting a new error on this line audio = whisper.load_audio(f.name): C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvuyq0_70: Permission denied @AKX

Comment: @IonicEcommerce Right – adapted for Windows, please see edit.